# Why should a group of order 33 have an element of order 3

Tags: group-theory

How do I show that $|G|=33$  has an element of order $3$. I could use Cauchy's and say that since $3$ is prime divisor of $33$ there must be a subgroup of order 3. But this problem shows up in Gilligan's book before Cauchy's theorem is introduced.
How do I prove this without Cauchy's.

Edit: we also haven't been introduced to Sylow, normal or quotient groups.